# path_helper is not loading paths from etc directory

Tags: osx, zsh

Currently I am using macOS Catalina, however this is same for couple of versions.

on `/etc/zprofile` (or `/etc/profile` when using bash back on old versions) I have such content by default:

```
if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi
```

In addition, I have create a file in `/etc/paths.d/android`. Content is

```
/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/tools
/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin
```

However when I launch terminal, terminal is not able to find my binaries in those folders:

```
zsh: command not found: adb
```

Don't know why, but workaround is duplicating path helper line as following?

```
if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi
```

So, here is my question, why is this happening and how this workaround actually works?

*I got bored workaround because it is just deleted every update.*

---

** Edit **

without duplication:

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/Users/\$USER/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/\$USER/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/\$USER/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:/Users/\$USER/Library/Flutter/bin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS:/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:/Users/$USER/Library/Flutter/bin"; export PATH;
```

```
print -lr -- $path[@]
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public
/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/tools
/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin
/Users/$USER/Library/Flutter/bin
/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS
```

with duplication:

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/Users/\$USER/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/\$USER/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/\$USER/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:/Users/\$USER/Library/Flutter/bin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS:/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:/Users/$USER/Library/Flutter/bin:/Users/guness/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/guness/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/guness/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:/Users/guness/Library/Flutter/bin"; export PATH;
```

```
print -lr -- $path[@]
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public
/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/tools
/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin
/Users/$USER/Library/Flutter/bin
/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS
/Users/guness/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
/Users/guness/Library/Android/sdk/tools
/Users/guness/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin
/Users/guness/Library/Flutter/bin
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the output of `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`, and the output of `print -lr -- $path[@]` with and without the duplication of the `eval …` line.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' you are a smart guy, it reveled problem. however still don't know how work around(!) works.

_output is added to the question_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution this is what I have done, I am still open to alternative solutions but putting mine as reference here.

```
if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    paths=`/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
    eval ${paths//'\$USER'/$'$USER'}
fi
```

it is just because first `path_helper` call generates path variable with escaped string as following: `/Users/\$USER/Library` and my fix is to unescape before evaluating.

---

Still, thanks to **@Gilles 'SO- stop being evil'** for helping me identify problem.